# Python Client/Server behind the router

Tags: python, client-server

I am looking for advice about technologies (and libraries) for develop client/server service program in Python. It can be run on static IP (it's Ok), dynamic IP, behind the router, mobile provider (so, it should work anywhere if possible). Port-forwading is not an option.

Main problem is connection:

- send: from Internet to computer behind the router
- listening of computer behind the router

Comment: How is the existence of the router relevant? It should be transparent and dealt with by the IP layer of the router. It's kind of the whole point of the router to route traffic to the correct end-point within the network...

Comment: Clear thoughts, thank you. I am not fluent in this question (that's why I am asking:), but typically you can't just access computer behind router (with NAT) from internet. Because, if it pings, you know only public IP, given by ISP. And if you want to connect to this computer somewhen you have only public IP. It would be great to create connection like 100.100.100.100/192.168.1.2 (Public IP/ Local IP), but I'm not sure it is possible in general. What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not a trivial one, but hopefully this can help you get going.  [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) is probably the best library for client/server code in python.  [STUN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Traversal_Utilities_for_NAT) and perhaps [TURN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traversal_Using_Relay_NAT) are generally the protocols for doing this sort of thing.

There's a [python library for STUN](http://code.google.com/p/pystun/), though I can't vouch for it.

Comment: Thank you for advice, STUN and TURN is the way to find the answer. Also there is great lection about my question from Yahoo, accessible from TURN wiki page. Twisted is nice framework, but it seems it doesn't support working behind NAT...I'm not sure completely, but [here](http://twistedmatrix.com/pipermail/twisted-python/2009-Octobe/020721.html) smb answers to this question.

Answer (score 1):

STUN has two versions: [RFC3489](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3489.txt), [RFC5389](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5389.txt) ,the latter is the new version . TURN is " Relay Extensions to Session Traversal Utilities for NAT (STUN) ", and can be found here [RFC5766](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5766.txt) .

STUN client : (RFC4389) [pystun](http://code.google.com/p/pystun/)  (in python)

TURN client : (also support STUN RFC5389) [turn-client](https://github.com/node/turn-client) (in python and C)

Answer (score 0):

pystun is now at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pystun

You can install it with pip:
pip install pystun